# How would I mount opposing knobs on a bifold door?

Tags: doors, knobs

This is for a bifold door. I want to have front and back knobs using the same screw.

I can’t recall what this assembly is called nor the screw name.

Comment: The  knob on the inside may keep the door from opening as far as it could otherwise. The knobs do not necessarily need to be connected. ( on the same plain)

Comment: I think I will get double ended screws. It’s ok not to have the dorms open flush. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @jlsdds, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what to do next. A comment is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't ever recall seeing a "kit" for this. When I've had to do it, I just got the two knobs and cut the head off one of the screws. If the screws that came with the knobs were too short, then I got a longer screw and cut the head off. There are double threaded studs out there but they are usually too big for what you want to do.

Comment: Your comment helped me to find double ended or dowel screws.

Comment: Jlsdds, when an answer is helpful please upvote or accept that’s how we give thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"I think AM's point is that you need opposing thread direction on each end. The threads would be backward for one side. –
isherwood." Totally wrong, you just need a suitable length of threaded rod or cut the head off a suitably long bolt. The thread doesn't need to be reversed. It's just the same as putting a nut on each side, you wouldn't need different threaded nuts. Threaded rod doesn't cost that much and you'll have it for future projects, working out much cheaper than buying bolts. If you've never cut threaded rod or a bolt before, put on a nut each side of the cut first, then when cut file the edges and thread slightly at 45degs, before taking the nut off to reset the thread. If you don't, sometimes you'll find a nut doesn't go back on easily or you can cross-thread the nut. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Assuming the knobs fit the thread of the rod, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a

[no-head bolt](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Hardware-Fasteners-Bolts/No-Head/N-5yc1vZc26wZ1z0y8k4)

and buy two handles.

Probably want about 2 1/2" length (*although depends on size of handles*)

Comment: No head bolt,  Also called Threaded Rod. Finding it with the correct threads for a door handle may be tricky.?? Depending on the knobs.

Comment: What I usually do is bring the item I'm threading (the knob) with me to Home Depot or Lowes and try until I find the right bolt.  (unless you can find the thread pitch labeled somewhere on the knob.)

Comment: I think AM's point is that you need opposing thread direction on each end. The threads would be backward for one side.

Comment: You shouldn't need special threading. The identical knobs will screw onto opposite ends of a threaded rod perfectly happily. Assuming these jobs fit the thread.